# LG Electric Range - Infinite switch burning up repeatedly, burner staying on high no matter what the setting

Tags: range, glass-top-range

I have an LG smooth-top Electric range, LDE4413ST, that keeps burning up infinite switches on the Right Front burner, which is a "dual element" burner.  This burner also operates at high power only,  this behavior seems to start when the switch burns up.

Here's what i've tried: 
- Tested  continuity on the wiring harness (seems fine, could not find a short)
- Tried  a replacement cooktop heating element (it operated at high power all the time, because the switch was bad and I didn't know it yet)
- Took out the replacement cooktop heating element and put the old one back in 
- Replaced the infinite switch since it was burned/scorched at the P1 terminal (replacing this worked for a few days, then stopped with scorch marks at the P1/Ls terminal.  When this happens there is continuity between this terminal and 2/H2, which I understand is not supposed to happen)
- Checking the cooktop heating element resistance on the original burner (was fine)

The range is an LG LDE4413ST. It is the right-front burner that is having this problem.

Everything else works on this range.

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: What is the model information on the side of the switch itself?

Comment: This is the LG Part Number: EBF62174902

Comment: Is something in the element grounding out or shorting and causing a full current draw?

Answer (score 3):

This can happen if the L1/L2 connections are swapped when a control/switch is replaced.  The element will work fine by itself.  Turn on another element at the same time that has the L1 connection to the other wire color, and the control will POP.  Both switches/elements will work separately.

The L1 tab of the switch is manually connected to the pilot when you activate the switch.  With the input wires swapped on one switch, you are putting L1/L2 together when both switches are turned on.

Both the switches that are connected to the same pilot light must have the same color wires connected to the same tabs, say red to L1 and black to L2.